# Workflow triggers

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a workflow set up where the workflow is triggered when a **certain Item is chang**ed. However, I noticed that when items are **edited** (changed) BEFORE all tasks from a previous workflow are COMPLETED (NOT STARTED), the workflow won't get triggered.

Is there any way that I can force the workflow to be triggered again only when all tasks are triggered?

Answer (score 2):

You can't start 2 instances of the same workflow on the item, the second workflow won't trigger if the first workflow is still working. You'll need to stop existing running workflow before starting the second.

Don't try to start the workflow from an external action if the current workflow is running on the item, by calling the workflow (there is an action that can be added in SharePoint Designer 2010) and also in Nintex, you will have an error stating your existing workflow is still running.

Comment: That's rather vague. Could you state how (and in what context) you're triggering the workflow? That said, it sound's like the having the workflow wait for task completion for each task might help you. Alternatively, an event receiver might be better suited for what you've described thus far. I'll edit my post to be more helpful when you clarify the above.

Comment: Agree with Mohammed. The answer to the @Kris question is 'no'. 
I am also curious as to the need and appropriateness of the solution. It could cause some inconsistency in understanding and approval, such that multiple users are approving different versions of an item, with each of them thinking everyone is approving the same item version. Can you shed light on the particulars of your business problem?

Comment: There is an end-user A that submits an item to another person B. He/she decides whether more information needs to be collected, or whether the item can be accepted or rejected to yet another person C. Once the end-user A submits his feedback (i.e. changes the item), the person B again verifies if it more info is needed, rejected or can be submitted to person C. I think stopping the workflow once feedback is required, is the right the to do.

Comment: I'm automatically triggering the workflow once an item is created. I don't think the "wait option" is good here, since users can edit items as long as it is not submitted to person C.

Comment: Yes, the workflow should start on item updated or item created.